# CSS: put search button inline to input when pull-left and pull-right don't work

Tags: html, css

I need to put the Search Button next to the Search Input, that is a list of options.

I've search and most of the answers say I need to use `pull-left` and `pull-right` classes but it is nor working in my case.

**Here is the Codepen:**

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/rNNVOBr

**Complete PageCode:**

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/rNNVOBr

**CodePen using diplay:flex:**

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/ExxjVqa

[image]

**Original HTML:**

```
<div class="row margin-top3 margin-bottom5 ">

        <form method="get" action="{% url 'shop:catalogo' %}">
            <div style="display: inline;">
            <div class="input-group pull-left">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Categorías</label>
                    <select class="custom-select" searchable="Search here.." value={{filtro}} name="filtro">
                        <option value="todas" disabled selected>Seleccionar categoría</option>
                        <option value="todas">Todas</option>
                        <option value="celulares">Celulares</option>
                        <option value="programacion">Programación</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-append pull-right">
                <p><input class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" name="buscar" value="Buscar" /></p>
            </div>
        </div>
            <!-- <p class="margin-top5">Ordenado por: <input class="disabled" type="text" value={{orderby}} name="orderby" /></p> -->
        </form>

</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

Heigh is increased:

[image]

Comment: you mean like this? https://codepen.io/rokobuljan/pen/rNNVOrb

Comment: PS... why the `<p>` around the input?

Comment: Yes, but with a margin between the elements. I also notice that the corners of the buttons are not rounded anymore.

Comment: @OmarGonzales Check my updated answer. It is working as intended now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use pull-left or pull-right. You have to simply put `<div class="input-group-append">` inside `<div class="input-group">` as it says in the [official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/).

```
<div class="row margin-top5 margin-bottom5 ">
    <form method="get" action="{% url 'shop:catalogo' %}">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Categorías</label>
            </div>
            <select class="custom-select" searchable="Search here.." value={{filtro}} name="filtro">
                <option value="todas" disabled selected>Seleccionar categoría</option>
                <option value="todas">Todas</option>
                <option value="celulares">Celulares</option>
                <option value="programacion">Programación</option>
            </select>
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <input class="btn btn-outline-secondary mb-0" type="submit" name="buscar" value="Buscar" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Ty, but height of pre-append got increased, why? See updated image.

Comment: @OmarGonzales It was because of the `<p>` tag on the input below. I've just updated. Can you please check now, please...

Comment: Not quite yet, please see the new codepen with the full page code. Ty.

Comment: @OmarGonzales I found the solution. Just add `margin-bottom: 0px;` to `.btn` class. The height of pre-append is increasing because of this.

Comment: @OmarGonzales i added `margin-bottom: 0px;` inline into my code. It is working as intended.

Comment: But that is a base Bootstrap class that could change other elements in other pages. How can I only affect this button?

Comment: @OmarGonzales just add `mb-0` to it. It will remove margin only for this element.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using CSS grid, you're kind of reinventing the wheel here.

CSS

```
.container{
  width: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class='label'>Select</div>
  <select>
    <option>Select an Option</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
  </select>
  <button>Search</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `display:flex` instead of float's because they are more predictable. In your case it will be something like [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/ashylen/pen/yLLNYjR). I assumed that you are using Bootstrap 4.

On the other hand, you shouldn't put `display:inline` to wrap other elements because they are not meant to be a wrappers. You can find more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

Comment: Ty. I still see some miss aligment in the "Buscar" button. I've updated my question with a CodePen using the display:flex option. May you check this out.

Comment: Just add `m-0` class to your input so the result is: `<input class="m-0 btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" name="buscar" value="Buscar">`.
Read [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) for more informations.